# How to crop or get a smaller size UIImage in iPhone without memory leaks?

Tags: iphone

I am using a navigation controller in which I push a tableview Controller as follows:

TableView *Controller = [[TableView alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:Controller animated:NO];
[Controller release];

In this table view I am using following two methods to display images:

```
- (UIImage*) getSmallImage:(UIImage*) img
{
    CGSize size = img.size;
    CGFloat ratio = 0;
    if (size.width < size.height) {
        ratio = 36 / size.width;
    } else {
        ratio = 36 / size.height;
    }
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, ratio * size.width, ratio * size.height);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    [img drawInRect:rect];

    return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}

- (UIImage*)imageByCropping:(UIImage *)imageToCrop toRect:(CGRect)rect
{

    //create a context to do our clipping in
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    //create a rect with the size we want to crop the image to
    //the X and Y here are zero so we start at the beginning of our
    //newly created context

    CGFloat X = (imageToCrop.size.width - rect.size.width)/2;
    CGFloat Y = (imageToCrop.size.height - rect.size.height)/2;


    CGRect clippedRect = CGRectMake(X, Y, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
    //CGContextClipToRect( currentContext, clippedRect);



    //create a rect equivalent to the full size of the image
    //offset the rect by the X and Y we want to start the crop
    //from in order to cut off anything before them
    CGRect drawRect = CGRectMake(0,
                                 0,
                                 imageToCrop.size.width,
                                 imageToCrop.size.height);

    CGContextTranslateCTM(currentContext, 0.0, drawRect.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(currentContext, 1.0, -1.0);
    //draw the image to our clipped context using our offset rect
    //CGContextDrawImage(currentContext, drawRect, imageToCrop.CGImage);


    CGImageRef tmp = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(imageToCrop.CGImage, clippedRect);

    //pull the image from our cropped context
    UIImage *cropped = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:tmp];//UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    CGImageRelease(tmp);
    //pop the context to get back to the default
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    //Note: this is autoreleased*/
    return cropped;
}
```

But when I pop the Controller, the memory being used is not released.
Is there any leaks in the above code used to create and crop images.

Also are there any efficient method to deal with images in iPhone. I am having a lot of images and facing major challeges in resolving the memory issues.

tnx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

i dunno about that, but this might be a problem:

```
return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

the second line is never run, because the first one returns